# Realistically would the government try to capture a person with powerful psychokinetic powers?

Tags: internal-consistency, government, super-powers

And Which government agency would even be the ones tasked with hunting you down? And what's a way that they would find out about you? I'd have to guess that most people would have the common sense to hide their powers from the public (unless forced like using them to save someone ECT...) However with the age of ever advancing technology they would have to find out what you're capable of eventually wither the ways were illegal or not right?

How would the government even go about trying to capture said person without alerting the entire public to said presence? Would they even let the public know about the worlds first superpowered human being or keep it under wrap? After all If the public did find out and the government did harm or kill them I could imagine the public outcry would be massive for killing the only known superpowered person in existence.

Would it be far fetched to say the government would use your loved ones against you as a kind of bait and interrogate them about everything they know about you? Where would they even take them to do such things to them? Would that even be legal for them to do?

What are some other ways the government would go about trying to capture you? And if capturing you proved to not be a choice anymore would there be any real world man made weapons that would even work against a person with telekinetic powers?

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to the site, please take the tour.  This needs some changes to meet the site format, unfortunately.  First, only one question per, well, question - there are at least 11 questions here.  Second, questions need to be structured so that answers are not story-based (it's your choice whether the government will chase someone) or opinion based (whether the government would publicly admit they are hunting a super-being).  Finally, we need enough information to formulate an answer, otherwise someone may say the NYPD would hunt them down but your story is set in South Africa.

Comment: That's a lot of questions and they all seems to be story oriented. Please check the site help center https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 more questions ask multiple questions on this forum. Personally I just read how would a government react to such a person and the other questions are specifications that you can think about.

Comment: The U.S. Government DOES have a top-secret program to enslave folks with psychic and psychokinetic and other mental powers. It's in the Department of Agriculture. It's a nefarious government plot to create a breakfast cereal that is both sugary-yummy *and* nutritious for children. It's been running since 1947, without much success.

Answer (score 4):

**Ask nicely**

Although television might suggest otherwise, a government's first reaction is to ask nicely for cooperation. Hunting down such people is counterproductive. You either kill them, wasting any potential, or antagonise a powerful individual, making him/her a risk for your highly trained personnel, the public at large and structures.

On the other side, offering a job with a shitload of money where they cooperate to get a good value out of the person in either labour or science is much more logical. Even if you give them millions, it's probably a lot cheaper. No secret facilities that require to contain the individuals, expensive hardware and trained personnel for hunting and containing, etc. Just the research with a cooperating person.

Perceived risks like losing the job or endangering friends would probably reduce the chance the powerd people from telling many. Because the international community or other governments would be interested with all added risks. But even if they might tell many and word gets around, they could be protected by the government or international community much like famous at risk celebrities. Added to this they can defend themselves. As long as this doesn't offset their worth too much, they would be relatively safe and happy.

Answer (score -1):

Power corrupts. Absolute power corrupts absolutely.

You cant hide this. Think back to your childhood, or even to today. If you got control of this early you could let your parents let you stay up late. That candy is nice and if only the guy behind the counter was nice he would make an exception for you. Like all children you've boasted about your capabilities, you were obviously the fastest, strongest, the best at getting laid etc. Are there no moments where you would like to erase a shaming thing you did from people's minds? Or where you would get back at a bully without risking yourself? You could publicly humiliate him by making him pee his/her pants, or make the bully apologise in front of everyone to teach him some humility. Or that funny looking boy or girl, maybe the fat one? You could have fun with them. Make him unable to use a single letter for a while, help them get out of their shell and dance in front of everyone. Its just a joke, or helping them right? And that one-night stand you wanted to hook up with? Just helping her have have a good time!

What about politics? I'm sure you've debated something with someone or listened to some politician on the news and if they just saw your point clearly they would do the right thing, right? Well you can skip that annoying debate as that just makes them defensive and help them do the right thing. After all, your opinion is the iron-clad truth right? And since you do such good things for your community/country/the world you should get paid right? So lets just convince a few people that some of that tax-payer money goes to you or those bills dont need paying by you, you worked hard for it after all.

Justifying this to yourself is easy if you rarely have to deal with the consequences. Note how I wrote these situations already covering the person from repercussions by saying its their reward or for the good of people/communities. Its not bullying if you are making a joke or forcing someone to do something they dont want for their own good right? Rape? She wanted it right? There's definitely no connection between making her want this and drugging her so she'll have sex with you right?

The big point of all of that: you'll get caught quickly after these powers develop because human nature is human nature, and too many camera's, administrative things and people changing their minds suddenly will happen when you are around. As Trioxidane says, someone from the government will simply be send to your house and ask you to come with them. If the government is smart they let the psychokinetic force that person to tell only the truth for a while, and that person explains exactly why he's there and what they intend to do (assuming a good government). They would guide the psychokinetic, and make sure he does not have to rely on his abilities to make it through life. That way they can teach him how to use the powers responsibly and sparingly.

If you flee, regular methods to find you would work fine, with the exception of asking people about you directly. If they get you once, the application of tracking things on your clothes and possessions would allow them to easily find you again. They probably know your size and weight, and the application of debilitating gasses or substances, like a rubber bullet to the chest, would easily reduce your psychokinetic capabilities.

Answer (score -2):

**MK Ultra**

If you ever ask yourself "Would the Government do that ?", the answer is most likely "yes". Thus, i am pretty sure "the government" would try to capture you. If they knew you existed.

Because, in the end the Government at larg isn´t very competent. But small parts of it can be. Such as the CIA or NSA.

**How do they find you ?**

Ill draw some parallels to a short story of mine in which a person with such powers get´s captured. But in her case she also can´t die which made to process of finding her easy.
So, how ? Well they either find you because they look for someone like you or you just happen to be at the wrong place at the wrong time.

So let´s say you are near a CIA employe when you use your powers. This person will probably tell there boss.

But they might just look for you, meaning they are aware of the fact that people like you are a thing. In my story, so called META Humans are very rare, as most just die of cancer or dont even live. But some do and over the last 200 Years or so, some parts of the Government became aware, thus looking for them.

Depending on what kind of story you write, if there are more then just one with powers, it isn´t strange to think that the Government just knows people like you exsist.

**How to capture the flag**

No Agency in the world will just rush b and try to capture you. Assuming they have even the smallest idea of what you can do. Unlike in Movies, Military commanders dont tend to send there troops into meatgrinder.
They would study you from a far and try to figure out as much as they can. Maybe even send in a Spy to start a friendship ? The goal being to find out what your weaknesses are. Because everyone and everything has one.
In my Short for example, she can only Manipulate conductiv Materials such as Metal. Finding that out isn´t that hard, thus they knew how to get her at long ranges.
Same goes for your Person. Even IF there power´s allow them to manipulate everything, something must work. Idk, maybe the power can be overpowered by a Magnet or dosnt work in Cold weather.

There of course can be a different tactic. Just like, talk to them. This runs into a few problems. Firstly, you sort of tell the Superhuman that they either cooperate with you or are forced to cooperate.
But if you approach it the right way, you may be able to convince them to work with you. I would say the Government would try that if they see you fighting for them. But really if they just want to know how you work, they may just dont ask.

The Tactic used depends a lot on the person(s) in charge though.

**Incarceration**

In a realistic world, the cell for you is the last thing they build before capturing you. They need to make sure you cant get out.
In my case, she had 3 Powers, telekinesis, Teleportation and immortality. The cell had to be designed accordingly. For example, its under ground so she cant just Teleport out. Then, she has a collar with Explosivs that go of when she is outside the cell. Then there are Sensors all over the place that detect if she uses her telekinesis, setting of the Bomb.
Your case may be different. But if we only have telekinesis, it stands to reason that you need some sort of Shield where the power cant go through. Maybe its just a giant Metal box with no windows if a transparent shield isnt an option.
Needless to say, if you ever find yourself in such a cell, dont expect to get out of there anytime soon.

**Why would they capture you in the first place ?**

As said before, there are 2 Options for what they do. Either they capture you or they talk to you.
What they do is dependend a lot on you and what you do. If you seem like a risk, they may not go easy on you. If you dont, well they might talk.
But unlike what some other people may think, i think most Governments would go for containment. No one likes it to have something powefull running around that is not in there control. Same here, even if you never did anything, there is really nothing that can stop you. So why not go the easy way and just Contain you ? This way, the Government or the Agency has full control.

**Who ?**

As i said, you will probably be captured by the agency that first found you. In my case, the Internal Agency just happend to be the Organisation that first saw META Humans. And they keep it by themselfs.
In your case, it could be the CIA, DARPA, Air Force or whatever. Point is, all of them have enough money to capture you. And non of them have any interesst in sharing you.

Think of how modern agency´s sort of waste there budget on useless stuff just so they dont get less money next year. Yeah no imagne them telling everyone "We have a Superpower Huamn". The first thing that will happen is that a new Agency ill be established and bam, there goes your Superhuman and a part of your budget.

**What then ?**

*Depends. . .* I dont belive whatever Agency you end up with, that they will just throw you into a cell and call it mission accomplished.
But also dont think they will just start going all Saw on you. They are still Humans, and so are you.
They will ask a ton of questions. They will try to learn everything about you and your power. They will ask you to do some test´s for them. And they will probably take a look inside you. Maybe just an MRI. But they will probably open you up to.

To make it short, they wont be sadistical or something like that. There is no reason for that.